# Redux-saga setContext not available in other saga

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'd just like context to be accessible from all sagas.

```
// Saga.js
function* test1() {
  const foo = yield getContext('foo');
  if (!foo) yield setContext({ foo: 'bar' });
  const test = yield getContext('foo');
  console.log(test); // Correct 'bar'.
}

function* test2() {
  const getFooValue = yield fork(test1); // This doesnt return getContext or the context value of foo
  // Do stuff here.
}
```

And the middleware

```
// TheStore.js
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({
  context: {
    foo: '',
  },
});

const TheStore: Store<ReduxState, *> = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);
```

Comment: If you set context in some saga you can access it only in the same saga or in sagas that you called/forked from the first one. (resp. in sagas deeper in the saga callstack).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I edited the code, so I am just trying to get the value of 'foo' in the test2 saga.  In test1 I want to either return the value of foo if it's defined, or define it then return the value.  Once foo has been defined, I don't want to have to redefine it ever.  Any help is appreciated or if there is any documentation somewhere that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the value of foo, you can do:

```
// Saga.js
function* test1() {
  const foo = yield getContext('foo');
  if (!foo) yield setContext({ foo: 'bar' });
  const test = yield getContext('foo');
  console.log(test); // Correct 'bar'.
  return test;
}

function* test2() {
  const getFooValue = yield call(test1); // This will now return the value of foo
  // Do stuff here.
}
```

`fork` will not wait for test1 to finish before executing the next lines of code.  `call` will wait for test1 to finish and grab the return value.